# Putting properties file into a JTree rather than just displaying it

Tags: java, swing, jtree, properties-file

This is my current code - it just displays the key pair values from my GitCommands.properties file and displays it in my GetAllProperties.java file - is it possible to sort it so it goes in to a JTree rather than just displaying it in a list type format?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;

public class GetAllProperties {
    private static JTree tree;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            String filename = "GitCommands.properties";
            // File file = new
            // File("/ApplicationTest/.settings/GitCommands.properties");
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filename);

            // load properties file
            properties.load(fileInputStream);

            System.out.println("keys avialble in Properties Files are:");
            System.out.println(properties.keySet());

            System.out.println("Key Value Pairs :");
            Enumeration enumeration = properties.keys();
            while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
                String key = (String) enumeration.nextElement();
                System.out.println(key + ": " + properties.get(key));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure a tree makes sense, but yes it's possible.  Have a look at [How to Use Trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html).  A `JTable` might make better sense, see [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: It may seem a little odd but I'm not allowed to use a table it has to be a tree :( Would you mind possibly pointing me in the right direction please? I have looked at a lot of examples but not come across one that puts the properties file into a JTree yet, thanks for your reply!

Comment: Well, that's the question, what is a node and what is a leaf?

Comment: I want to have a root file called GIT commands and when that is clicked it opens up to display all the GIT command keys as the nodes. Once each individual node is then clicked I want it to display the description string from that same properties file into a panel on the right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply populate the tree using the tree model

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(filename);
DefaultTreeModel treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);

Enumeration enumeration = properties.keys();  
while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {  
    String key = (String) enumeration.nextElement();
    String nodeObj = key+" : "+properties.get(key);
    treeModel.insertNodeInto(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(nodeObj), root, 0);
}

JTree tree = new JTree(treeModel);
```

NOTE: the elements are not sorted... to do so, you need to push all keys into a list and sort that list

```
List sortedList<String> = new ArrayList<String>();
Enumeration enumeration = properties.keys();  
while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {  
    String key = (String) enumeration.nextElement();
    sortedList.add(key);
}
Collection.sort(sortedList);

for(String key: sortedList){
    String nodeObj = key+" : "+properties.get(key);
    // [...] same as above
}
```

Comment: ah thankyou! I've already got my jtree populating but not in order I was wondering how to go about it,thanks for the help! ^.^

Comment: Thank you!It's finally starting to make a bit of sense haha :)

Comment: I'm getting an error on the code, saying { is expected after     Enumeration enumeration = properties.keys(); in the first section of the code, if i put { in it then underlines "collection"  Collection.sort(sortedList); and "sortedList"  for(String key: sortedList){ .... do you have any idea how to fix that? :)

Comment: it should be "Collections" using this java.util.Collections;  i missed an 's', sorry

Comment: Ah I can't believe I didn't realise myself that, thats what it was haha thankyou!

Comment: i didn't mind ^^ sorry, i wrote that code directly in tackOverflow, i didn't copy/paste from Eclipse... i hope there are no more typos in it!

Comment: It's fine now it just still says saying { is expected after Enumeration enumeration = properties.keys(); unfortunately!

Comment: looks like there is a bracket '{' missing, it could be a bracket at any part of your code - check if all brackets are opened/closed properly...

Comment: It was telling me to add another to close class body so I did that so now I have a bracket too many but if  I remove it it I get the error back, I think I'm missing one from some where but I just don't know where to put it :(