# Retrieving values from properties file when key node is clicked in JTree

Tags: java, swing, panel, key-value, jtree

I have a Jtree that displays all the keys in my properties file - however when I click on a node I want it to obtain the value that goes with the currently selected key and display it in my panel on the right of my Jtree. I have my code below, if anyone knows how I'd display that it would a big help!

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeSelectionModel;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class HelpSystem implements TreeSelectionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textFieldSearch;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {                   
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    HelpSystem window = new HelpSystem();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public HelpSystem() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 842, 516);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[grow]", "[][grow]"));
        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane();
        frame.getContentPane().add(splitPane, "cell 0 1,grow");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        splitPane.setRightComponent(panel);
        panel.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[]", "[]"));
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        splitPane.setLeftComponent(tabbedPane);
        JPanel panelSearch = new JPanel();
        panelSearch.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(7, 10));
        tabbedPane.addTab("Search", null, panelSearch, null);
        panelSearch.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[][][]", "[][][][][][][][][]"));
        JLabel lblSearchForGit = new JLabel("Search for Git command:");
        panelSearch.add(lblSearchForGit, "cell 0 1,alignx center");
        textFieldSearch = new JTextField();
        panelSearch.add(textFieldSearch, "cell 0 3,growx");
        textFieldSearch.setColumns(10);
        JLabel lblSearchForGit_1 = new JLabel("search for git command to display info in the right");
        panelSearch.add(lblSearchForGit_1, "cell 0 8");
        JPanel panelLookup = new JPanel();
        panelLookup.setToolTipText("Lookup a command");
        tabbedPane.addTab("Lookup", null, panelLookup, null);
        panelLookup.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[grow][grow]", "[grow][grow][][][][][][][][][][]"));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        panelLookup.add(scrollPane, "flowx,cell 0 0 2 11,grow");
        ///Area related to displaying JTree inside jpanel /////
        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel_1.setSize(new Dimension(22, 0));
        scrollPane.setViewportView(panel_1);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            //properties file - get the data in the file
            String filename = "GitCommands.properties";
            // Properties p =System.getProperties();
            Properties p = properties;
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
            //load properties file  
            properties.load(fileInputStream);
            panel_1.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[64px][][][][][][][]", "[322px,grow,fill][][]"));
            //sets up a scroll pane to view all of the tree
            JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane();
            //frame.getContentPane().add(scrollpane, "Center");
            panel_1.add(scrollpane, "cell 0 5,alignx left,aligny top");

            //what will happen when the user closes the program
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            //sets new jtree
            final JTree tree = new JTree(p);
            //Where the tree is initialized:
            tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
            //Listen for when the selection changes.
            tree.addTreeSelectionListener(this);
            panel_1.add(tree, "cell 7 0 1 3");
            tree.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
            tree.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 40, 0));
            tree.setToolTipText("Click a command");
            //sort in to order
            //allows the root of the tree to be shown
            tree.setRootVisible(true);
            //re size the width
            tree.setSize(20, 10);
            //it will be visible
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
        //
    }
}
```

Then I have my method to go with the listener for the event of the node being clicked

```
private void createSelectionListener(Object node) {
     //if nothing is selected  
     if (node == null) return;
          // retrieve the node that was selected 
          Object nodeInfo = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) node).getUserObject();
          // What happens when node is clicked 
     }
}
```

I am just unsure of what to put underneath //what happens when node is clicked in order to get it display?

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for JTree/TreeModel

Comment: Would posting my entire code be better?

Comment: :-) yes, it should be short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for JTree/TreeModel

Comment: Well im just using the one class,but its not exactly short but I cant cut it down otherwise it wouldn't run, is it okay to post the class still or would that be too much?

Comment: It does not seem to make much sense to me, to load the keys then later load the values.  Do it all at the same moment!  Store each Key/Value pair as a `NamedAttribute` (or something else meaningful).  Put `NamedAttribute` objects into the tree using an appropriate renderer (that displays the key).

Comment: I basically have two panels side by side - the left needs to have the jtree store the keys then when the keys are clicked they need to display in the right hand panel - Can I still do that how you are suggesting?

Comment: Edits, but not an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  Please read the linked article.

Comment: I've cut it down to the bare minimum I possibly can now :)

Comment: 1. code missed two } braces 2. public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {, 3. for why reason you killed MigLayout by setBounds/setSize, call JFrame.pack() before setVisible() 4. you have to load properties file to array (util.List ???) defined as local variable, every of Object has index, you have to load this index to the DefaultTreeModel 5. and to change this value in TreeCellRenderer to something, whetever reasonable from underlaying array 6. then selection from TreeSelectionListener can to returns (depends of methods you'll used for) a) index or b) description (visible in JTree)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your question is a continuation of the one you've [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25399983/putting-properties-file-into-a-jtree-rather-than-just-displaying-it). What you want is to utilize a [Tree Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/treeselectionlistener.html).

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;


public class GetAllProperties extends JFrame {

    private static final String NOTHING_SELECTED = "<nothing selected>";

    private final JScrollPane treeScroll;
    private final JTree tree;
    private final DefaultTreeModel treeModel;
    private final DefaultMutableTreeNode root;
    private final JLabel descriptionLabel;

    private Properties properties;

    public GetAllProperties() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("GIT commands");
        treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
        tree = new JTree(treeModel);
        treeScroll = new JScrollPane(tree);
        add(treeScroll, BorderLayout.WEST);

        populateTree();        

        descriptionLabel = new JLabel(NOTHING_SELECTED);
        add(descriptionLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {

            public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode selection = 
                        (DefaultMutableTreeNode)tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
                if (selection != null) {
                    String key = (String)selection.getUserObject();
                    String command = properties.getProperty(key);
                    descriptionLabel.setText(command);
                } else {
                    descriptionLabel.setText(NOTHING_SELECTED);
                }
            }
        });

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new GetAllProperties().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private void populateTree() {
        // fake properties in order to avoid IO
        properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("foo1", "bar1");
        properties.setProperty("foo2", "bar2");
        properties.setProperty("foo3", "bar3");
        properties.setProperty("foo4", "bar4");

        Set<Object> keySet = properties.keySet();
        for (Object key : keySet) {
            root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(key));
        }

        tree.expandPath(new TreePath(root));
    }

}
```

You really should consider reading and understanding the [How to use Trees tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html), like it has already been suggested to you.

I wanted to answer your prior question with the above code, but was to late, so here you go.

Comment: That was very helpful so thankyou very much - I have read the tutorials the only thing that stumps me is placing corresponding values out of the properties file and into a panel once the individual keys have been clicked on. Everything I have seen appears to have hard coded values on them which is not how mine works :(

Comment: From a general perspective, there's not much difference between hard-coding those properties and loading them from a file. I abstracted that away in order to focus on what's relevant to your question.